# Losing precision while printing float

Tags: java, string, floating-point-precision

Please have a look at the below code:

```
    float num =  72000000.69f; 
    System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", num));
```

Output: 72000000.00

I am loosing the precision. I have tried by converting to float to BigDecimal and then printing the values, but it doesn't help.

Any way to preserve the precision?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A float has seven digits of precision.   You got your seven digits.

If you want greater precision, use a double instead.

Comment: Hi Curt. From where did you get this information that float has seven digits of precision? Will it be possible for you to share some link?

Comment: Hey i got that on wiki. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
BigDecimal num = new BigDecimal("72000000.69");
System.out.println(num);
```

Output:

```
72000000.69
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **BigDecimal**, floating types don't store all your number the way you think

Comment: The problem is that i am getting this value from another application which is sending it as a float value. I do not have the privilege of changing the data type as of now. However, if we are sure there is no other option, i can raise this to the higher-ups.

Answer (score 0):

Try this test

```
    System.out.println(72000000.69f == 72000000f);
```

it prints

```
true
```

this means .69 is simply cut off due to float's low precision, it's simply not there, you cant restore it by any means.